# Is it possible to show one string or the other (Mandatory case) in the same textview

Tags: android, string, android-intent, textview

I have to different `Strings`.

1. One is taken from the `ListViewItem` when clicked
2. The other from `EditText` when pressed a button

Both being sent to the same a common activity using via Intent and either one (Mandatory) needs to be displayed in same `TextView`. I have tried the below code however, if both strings are executed, one results in null.

Code passed from listview to common activity:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Appliances_Model app_value = (Appliances_Model)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

    String str_app_test = app_value.app_mod_name;
    String str_app_testid = app_value.appliances_id;
    Log.d("check model name ", str_app_test);
    Log.d("checkid ", str_app_testid);

    Intent i67 = new Intent(this, ChecksAndOperations.class);  // common class
    i67.putExtra("selected appliance model name", str_app_test); // sending to the common class
    i67.putExtra("selected appliance id", str_app_testid);

    startActivity(i67);

}
```

Code receiving listview item in a textview `appliance_no`:

```
passedListValuAppModName = getIntent().getStringExtra("selected appliance model name");
    appliance_no.setText(passedListValuAppModName);
```

Sending edittext value

```
Intent i3 = new Intent(this, ChecksAndOperations.class);
            i3.putExtra("Appliance No", lastRowId);
            startActivity(i3);
```

Recieving value of edittext in the text`appliance_no`:

```
appliance_no = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.displayApplianceNo); //Text that has to display either of the two string
    Bundle carrier1 = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(carrier1 == null)
    {
        return;         
    }

    String brough_app_no= carrier1.getString("Appliance No");
    if (brough_app_no != null )
    {
        appliance_no.setText(brough_app_no);
    }
```

Not sure, if what i'm trying to achieve even possible?

Comment: Do you mean the TextView is changed when a) ListView item is clicked b) button is clicked? What is the problem then?

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for replying. I meant just the content of TextView should change. Anyway I managed to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I was just inserting the code which is recieving the string for the ListViewItem above the the bundle however it should come after checking the condition, if the bundle is null

```
appliance_no = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.displayApplianceNo);
    Bundle carrier1 = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(carrier1 == null)
    {

        return;         
    }

    passedListValuAppModName = getIntent().getStringExtra("selected appliance model name");
    appliance_no.setText(passedListValuAppModName);
    passedListAppId = getIntent().getStringExtra("selected appliance id");


    String brough_app_no= carrier1.getString("Appliance No");
    if (brough_app_no != null )
    {
        appliance_no.setText(brough_app_no);
    }
```